# Get multiple custom taxonomy and terms index using json-api

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy, wordpress-json-api

I use [json-api plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) and I have three custom taxonomies. for example: car, phone, and book. I try to get all taxonomy index something like this

http://example.com/api/taxonomy/get_taxonomy_index/?taxonomy=car,phone,book

But it doesn't work for more than one taxonomy. Does Anyone know how to get all my custom taxonomy and terms index?

Here is JSON_API_Taxonomy_Controller:

```
class JSON_API_Taxonomy_Controller {

    public function get_taxonomy_index() {
        $terms = $this->get_terms();
        return array(
            'count' => count( $terms ),
            'terms' => $terms
        );
    }

    public function get_terms() {
        global $json_api;
        $taxonomy = $this->get_current_taxonomy();
        if (!$taxonomy) {
            $json_api->error("Not found.");
        }

        $wp_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
        $terms = array();
        foreach ( $wp_terms as $wp_term ) {
            if ( $wp_term->term_id == 1 && $wp_term->slug == 'uncategorized' ) {
                continue;
            }
            $terms[] = new JSON_API_Term( $wp_term );
        }
        return $terms;
    }

    protected function get_current_taxonomy() {
        global $json_api;
        $taxonomy  = $json_api->query->get('taxonomy');
        if ( $taxonomy ) {
            return $taxonomy;
        } else {
            $json_api->error("Include 'taxonomy' var in your request.");
        }
        return null;
    }
}

// Generic rewrite of JSON_API_Tag class to represent any term of any type of taxonomy in WP
class JSON_API_Term {

  var $id;          // Integer
  var $slug;        // String
  var $title;       // String
  var $description; // String

  function JSON_API_Term($term = null) {
    if ($term) {
      $this->import_wp_object($term);
    }
  }

  function import_wp_object($term) {
    $this->id = (int) $term->term_id;
    $this->slug = $term->slug;
    $this->title = $term->name;
    $this->description = $term->description;
    $this->post_count = (int) $term->count;
  }

}
```

So I want json object output: registered taxonomies as parent and terms as child.

Comment: Do you want to list all your registered taxonomies, or all terms within a taxonomy? I really didn't understand what you want

Comment: I want registered taxonomies as parent and terms as child.and output json like this: car:{BMW,Toyota} phone:{apple,smasung} book:{book1,book2}